# Redshift CTAS and AUTOCOMMIT

Tags: amazon-redshift, commit

I have a quick question about creating a table as a selection from another one.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
AS
(SELECT * FROM table2)
```

Does this kind of operation require an explicit commit?

Comment: DDL statemenst are transactional in Redhift, so if you have disabled autocommit, then yes it requires a commit.

Comment: NOTE WELL: TRUNCATE commits even when autocommit is off. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRUNCATE.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it after `BEGIN` then the answer is always yes.

If you run it without `BEGIN` then it depends on the driver/tool settings you're using to connect.

For JDBC in particular check your autocommit setting. Example:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html